# Vercel. Удаление файлов из папки static

Tags: удаление

При добавлении аватарки сохраняю ее в папку static:

```
    module.exports.addAvatar = (req, res, next) => {
  const avatar = req.files.avatar;
  User.findById(req.user._id)
  .then((user)=> {
      const avatarName = Uuid.v4()+'.jpg';
      console.log (avatarName);
      avatar.mv(`${'.\\static\\users'+'\\'+ avatarName}`);
      user.avatar = avatarName;
      user.save();
      res.send({ user });
  })
  .catch(new BadRequest('failed to upload file'))
  .catch(next)
```

Для редактирования/удаления использую   fs.unlink. При отправке запросов на локальный сервер все 3 запроса работают корректно. При отправке на сервер, расположенный на Vercel - первый(создание) работает корректно(отдает 200, имя файла сохраняется в БД), остальные 2 отдают ошибку. Предполагаю, что не работает именно удаление файлов.

В app прописано:

```
app.use(express.static(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '.vercel_build_output/static' : 'static'));
```

Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим?